# What is known about the classification of real functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, real-numbers, neural-networks, classifying-spaces

For every possible mapping on a set of real numbers to a set of real numbers, is there any overarching theory of their classification?

For example, some mappings aren’t defined by a formula but are just arbitrary mappings.

I’m not sure but I think every real function has to be defined in terms of operators that are themselves defined in terms of addition and multiplication, since those are the only two operations assigned to the field of real numbers. In other words, trigonometric functions and exponential functions have reformulations in addition and multiplication, if you can also use infinite limits.

Is there a known way of carving up the space of real functions by fundamental distinguishing properties or is it a partial classification in which certain subgroups are known, but they may partially overlap in irregular ways, and there may be currently unknown classes of functions?

As for why I want to know this, because I have been thinking about neural networks more abstractly and trying to consider what the abstract necessary characteristics are of an optimization function, to consider what valid alternatives to backpropagation could be by considering the space of all valid optimization functions; and to consider what abstract characteristics neural networks themselves have that allows them to do what they do; and similar questions.

Comment: There is about no reasonable classification. Even continuous functions can be real beast! Consider the function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \phi(x-n) p(n)$$ where $p(n)$ is the $n$th prime number and $\phi$ is your favourite nontrivial function that is smooth and has support in $(0,1/2)$. Then $f$ is smooth function. Now what kind of category would you like to throw this function into?

Comment: A couple notes: How would you interpret characteristic functions in terms of addition and multiplication? Such as $$1_{\lbrace 0\rbrace} (x) = 1 \text{ if }x=0, \: 0\text{ if }x\neq 0$$.
And there are so many wild real functions that no reasonable classification can exist.

However, restricting to analytic functions, you are right: Here the functions have power series, defined from addition and multiplication (as well as taking a limit).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I'm surprised that that function is smooth, since it has a discrete component p(n), but I guess the infinite sum causes it to act that way. As for classifying, how about first classifying it as a "smooth" function, and then sub-classifying based on what kinds of terms it has, like a prime number infinite sum?

Comment: It is not really surprising that it is smooth, the different "bumps" do not interfere with each other. Ok, there are plenty of regularity classes that are well-studied in analysis. That would be $C^k(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ (i.e. $k$-times differentiable and the $k$th derivative is continuous). More generally, there are the $C^{k,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ spaces ($k$-times differentiable and $k$th derivative is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous). There are the $L^p(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ (well, actually those are equivalence classes) catching integrability conditions.

Comment: There are weak $L^p$-spaces, Sobolev spaces (weak derivative exists and is in some $L^p$), weighted Sobolev spaces (all of this stuff can also be done with respect to a more general measure than the Lebesgue measure), Besov spaces, Gevrey spaces, Bohr almost continuous functions, Stepanov almost continuous functions, Besicovitch almost periodic functions, ... there tons of function spaces and we are far from understanding them. Consider for example the image of $L^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ under the Fourier transform, we do not really have a good way of classifying those functions.

Comment: All those function spaces are somewhat well-behaved (regularity or integrability) and can be made into Banach spaces. Now you are asking for a general classification of all nasty functions.... just hopeless. Also, why would we care? Typically we have some specific problem and that gives us plenty of constraints and then we study the space of functions that satisfy those constraints and that is already hard enough.